# Via Ansible to get the most recent war file from A nexus repo

Tags: ansible, nexus

I have, in nexus, a bunch of versions of .war files in my snapshot repo. As a part of an automated pipeline we would like to grab the newest version of these .war files via ansible.  When there is no .war file on the machine it does grab the newest version. (code below).

```
- name: Deploy War File
  maven_artifact: group_id=com.company artifact_id=sales-ui extension=war repository_url=http://ddnexusrepo:8081/nexus/content/repositories/{{repo}} username={{ nexus_user }} password={{ nexus_password }}  dest=/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/sales-ui.war
```

When it is already on the system it does not get updated when a newer version is in nexus.  How can I get it to grab the latest?

The only way I can think is to download (via the same maven_artifact module) the .war.md5 and compare it to the .war's md5 on the server to see if there was a change. Really what I want is a `state=latest` but the only functionality is present or absent. Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use version=latest tag which is available in ansible 2.2.1.0

Comment: It won't works if we need latest "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" version and there is "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT" in the same repo.